# Is there a fee for upgrading a deployed program?

Tags: upgrade

I deployed a program, but now I try to upgrade it still requires 1.78 SOL it seems, I had deposited about 3.8 SOL before for the program to be deployed. It seems a bit senseless to pay for every time I make a small change in the code?

Answer (score 2):

On upgrade, you need to have the requested amount of SOL in your wallet, but it will not be permanently charged. After the upgrade, you end up with roughly the same amount of SOL that you had just before the upgrade. There will just be a very low amount deducted for the actual transaction fees.

In my case, I had to deposit over 8 SOL to deploy my Program. Every upgrade requires 3.7 SOL in my wallet, but almost all of it is still in my wallet after the upgrade.

The transaction fees in this case were just a few cents.

Answer (score 2):

These lamports are to allocate a temporary program buffer account to deploy into.  Once the upgrade is complete it will be closed and the lamports recovered